# Plotting 3d surface from data points

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I have the following code which works great and produces the plot I want. This is it:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{filename.txt}
0 0 -0.64
1 0 -0.5
2 0 -0.4
3 0 -0.31
4 0 -0.23
5 0 -0.2
6 0 -0.24
7 0 -0.32
8 0 -0.42
9 0 -0.59
10 0 -0.76

0 1 -0.54
1 1 -0.4
2 1 -0.27
3 1 -0.17
4 1 -0.08
5 1 -0.03
6 1 -0.05
7 1 -0.14
8 1 -0.27
9 1 -0.45
10 1 -0.63

0 2 -0.46
1 2 -0.31
2 2 -0.16
3 2 -0.03
4 2 0.07
5 2 0.12
6 2 0.11
7 2 0.02
8 2 -0.13
9 2 -0.32
10 2 -0.51

0 3 -0.44
1 3 -0.26
2 3 -0.08
3 3 0.07
4 3 0.18
5 3 0.25
6 3 0.24
7 3 0.14
8 3 -0.01
9 3 -0.2
10 3 -0.41

0 4 -0.44
1 4 -0.26
2 4 -0.04
3 4 0.13
4 4 0.25
5 4 0.32
6 4 0.31
7 4 0.22
8 4 0.07
9 4 -0.14
10 4 -0.37

0 5 -0.44
1 5 -0.26
2 5 -0.05
3 5 0.14
4 5 0.27
5 5 0.34
6 5 0.33
7 5 0.24
8 5 0.09
9 5 -0.12
10 5 -0.36

0 6 -0.48
1 6 -0.29
2 6 -0.08
3 6 0.09
4 6 0.22
5 6 0.29
6 6 0.28
7 6 0.2
8 6 0.06
9 6 -0.13
10 6 -0.35

0 7 -0.55
1 7 -0.34
2 7 -0.15
3 7 -0.0
4 7 0.11
5 7 0.18
6 7 0.18
7 7 0.11
8 7 -0.02
9 7 -0.2
10 7 -0.39

0 8 -0.63
1 8 -0.44
2 8 -0.27
3 8 -0.13
4 8 -0.03
5 8 0.04
6 8 0.04
7 8 -0.02
8 8 -0.13
9 8 -0.29
10 8 -0.45

0 9 -0.71
1 9 -0.59
2 9 -0.43
3 9 -0.28
4 9 -0.18
5 9 -0.13
6 9 -0.13
7 9 -0.17
8 9 -0.26
9 9 -0.38
10 9 -0.53

0 10 -0.83
1 10 -0.75
2 10 -0.59
3 10 -0.45
4 10 -0.35
5 10 -0.3
6 10 -0.3
7 10 -0.34
8 10 -0.42
9 10 -0.52
10 10 -0.66
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={-20}{20}, grid=both]
      \addplot3[surf] file {filename.txt};
      %\addplot3[surf, point meta=explicit] table [z expr=0.5, meta index=2] {filename.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, my data points are the following:

```
    \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{filename.txt}

10  0   2.8637
15  0   2.8131
20  0   2.8727
25  0   2.8644
30  0   2.8842
35  0   2.8675
40  0   2.7089
45  0   2.6247

10  0.001   2.8436
15  0.001   2.8692
20  0.001   2.8859
25  0.001   2.4132
30  0.001   2.7664
35  0.001   2.8796
40  0.001   2.8752
45  0.001   2.8782

10  0.002   2.8752
15  0.002   2.8693
20  0.002   2.8703
25  0.002   2.6594
30  0.002   2.8643
35  0.002   2.5554
40  0.002   2.8875
45  0.002   2.8887

10  0.003   2.8151
15  0.003   2.8856
20  0.003   2.8701
25  0.003   2.857
30  0.003   2.8785
35  0.003   2.6176
40  0.003   2.8835
45  0.003   2.9234

10  0.004   2.8815
15  0.004   2.8792
20  0.004   2.8213
25  0.004   2.8877
30  0.004   2.9202
35  0.004   2.8595
40  0.004   2.885
45  0.004   2.8489

10  0.005   2.8907
15  0.005   2.8521
20  0.005   2.6148
25  0.005   2.8762
30  0.005   2.8576
35  0.005   2.8363
40  0.005   2.7048
45  0.005   2.7617

10  0.006   2.8599
15  0.006   2.8941
20  0.006   2.8474
25  0.006   2.876
30  0.006   2.8206
35  0.006   2.5735
40  0.006   2.3208
45  0.006   2.3754

10  0.007   2.8833
15  0.007   2.8886
20  0.007   2.8691
25  0.007   2.6355
30  0.007   2.7528
35  0.007   2.5829
40  0.007   2.583
45  0.007   2.5111

10  0.008   2.8711
15  0.008   2.8815
20  0.008   2.8452
25  0.008   2.7511
30  0.008   2.5907
35  0.008   2.5598
40  0.008   2.6029
45  0.008   2.5253

10  0.009   2.8708
15  0.009   2.6844
20  0.009   2.7038
25  0.009   2.6988
30  0.009   2.4988
35  0.009   2.4059
40  0.009   1.8292
45  0.009   2.2368

10  0.01    2.8806
15  0.01    2.8899
20  0.01    2.386
25  0.01    2.5372
30  0.01    2.3707
35  0.01    2.1165
40  0.01    2.1553
45  0.01    2.3411

10  0.011   2.8725
15  0.011   2.7136
20  0.011   2.5851
25  0.011   2.4942
30  0.011   2.478
35  0.011   2.3578
40  0.011   2.465
45  0.011   2.0726

10  0.012   2.8873
15  0.012   2.6652
20  0.012   2.6406
25  0.012   2.4053
30  0.012   2.3922
35  0.012   2.3308
40  0.012   2.3423
45  0.012   2.0778

10  0.013   2.8902
15  0.013   2.7437
20  0.013   2.6815
25  0.013   2.2707
30  0.013   2.1961
35  0.013   2.1585
40  0.013   2.2469
45  0.013   2.3896

10  0.014   2.8826
15  0.014   2.6679
20  0.014   2.4037
25  0.014   2.2751
30  0.014   2.3569
35  0.014   2.3838
40  0.014   2.2706
45  0.014   2.2171

10  0.015   2.8688
15  0.015   2.5697
20  0.015   2.4726
25  0.015   2.2542
30  0.015   2.344
35  0.015   2.3119
40  0.015   2.0676
45  0.015   2.2591

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={-20}{35}, grid=both]
    \addplot3[surf] file {filename.txt};
%   \addplot3[surf, point meta=explicit] table [z expr=0.2, meta index=2] {filename.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And get the following disaster:
[image]

> Could you tell me whats going on and how could I fix this issue? I need to fix the scale where it says **10^-2**. I want to have on the x axis **from 0 to 0.015 with steps of 0.001**
>
> This is the desired output:
>   [image]

Comment: How is it a disaster, doesn't the plot show the data points?

Comment: Yeah but it is a flat surface. Maybe one could add a function to it and make it look like the updated post!

Comment: It's multiple flat surfaces joined together, isn't it? Your first example is exactly the same.

Comment: I think I  am lacking some data points. I am recompiling the code so I get more data points

Comment: Probably, the data file you showed had 4 samples in both x and y, so you get a surface that is 3x3 panels, while the image you showed clearly has more.

Comment: Could you help me with the scale? Meaning, on the x axis from 0 to 0.015 with steps of 0.001

Comment: `ytick={0,0.005,0.01,0.015}, scaled y ticks=false, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3}`. Still though, the output is not really a disaster, `pgfplots` is just showing the numbers you give it. If the plot is wrong, the numbers are wrong, and you need to look at how you generated those numbers.